# Arduino data type confusion. Have string, need const char?

Tags: c, arduino, type-conversion

I'm working with an UNO and I'm using maniacbug's RF24 library with soft spi, and his rf24network library. https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24Network

All I'm trying to do is send data but I'm stuck with the wrong data type.

```
{
last_sent = now;

printf("Sending...\r\n");
const char* hello = "Hello, world!";
RF24NetworkHeader header(/*to node*/ other_node);
bool ok = network.write(header,hello,strlen(hello));
if (ok)
  printf("\tok.\r\n");
else
{
  printf("\tfailed.\r\n");
  delay(250); // extra delay on fail to keep light on longer
}
}
```

If I change it to

```
bool ok = network.write(header,myString,strlen(myString));
```

I get an error on data type.  So how do I get my string to fit this structure.  My thought was to to a myString.toCharArray then maybe loop through that?

Comment: What is `myString` and how is it declared??

Comment: @TheEditor - you should just use the `c_str()` method of the String class in the call to `network.write` I.e `network.write(header, myString.c_str(), myString.length());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the String into a char array first:

```
size_t len = myString.length();
char buf[len+1]; // +1 for the trailing zero terminator
myString.toCharArray(buf, len);
```

and then you can pass `buf`:

```
bool ok = network.write(header,buf,strlen(buf));
```